# Jasmine unit test for file size with TypeScript in Angular

Tags: angular, file, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

Searching for best practice how to test File size on input type="file" change event.

Right now my test spec looks like this:

```
it('attach file with too large size', () => {
  const file: File = {
    name: 'filename',
    type: 'image/png',
    size: 8242880,
    lastModified: 1,
    lastModifiedDate: new Date(),
    webkitRelativePath: '',
    msClose: () => {},
    msDetachStream: () => {},
    slice: (): Blob => null,
  };
  const event = { target: { files: [file] } };

  component.onFileChange(event); // file validation happens into it too

  const error = control.getError('file_size');
  expect(error).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Is there better way how to set File size property with TypeScript?
When I am trying to setting `size` property directly to File object, it's not allowed because `size` property is `read-only`.

```
const file = new File([''], 'filename', { type: 'image/png' });
file.size = 8242880; // TS error
```

Current way how I am mocking File object where I need to define all File object properties for me isn't looking very beautiful, but can't find any better way.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to overwrite the size property.

```
/** Creates a "1TB" file given the file name. */
function getHugeFile(name: string) : File {
  const file = new File([''], name);
  Object.defineProperty(
      file, 'size', {value: Math.pow(1024, 4), writable: false});
  return file;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to resolve the `TS error`, here is the ways,

```
interface IFile extends File {
    size: number;
}

const file: IFile = new File([''], 'filename', { type: 'image/png' });
file.size = 8242880; // Works..
```

Comment: Thanks for tip! It's one of ways how to remove TS error. My colleague give one more idea, where I move current File object to MockFile class and use this class for test purposes.

Answer (score 2):

How I solved it:

```
export const createFile = (params?: any): File  => {
  const file = {
    name: 'filename',
    type: 'image/png',
    size: 123,
    lastModified: 1,
    lastModifiedDate: new Date(),
    webkitRelativePath: '',
    msClose: () => {},
    msDetachStream: () => {},
    slice: (): Blob => null,
  };

  return {
    ...file,
    ...params,
  };
};
```

And use `createFile()` where is needed to mock file object.

Comment: I get TypeScript error Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Blob'.

Comment: Hmm, it's still showing error? Looked in my code and it works without any error.

Comment: For the null I used

`slice: (): Blob => new Blob,`